# In MVC, when do you use <%= %> and <% %>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc, when do we use:

and

Do we ever need to put a ; (colon) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<%= %>` renders the output (string) of the contained command to the response.  `<% %>` wraps executable statements (logic) in the view to control what gets executed.  You don't use semicolons in the `<%= %>` blocks, but may in the `<% %>` depending on what statements are included.

String rendering:

`<%= Html.Encode( Model. Property ) %>`

Code block:

`<% Html.RenderPartial( "ViewName" ); %>`

**EDIT:** Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx) to the reference.

Comment: Correct. Same rules as in ASP.NET and ASP Classic apply.

Answer (score 4):

`<%="something" %>` is just a shortcut for `Response.Write("something")`

Answer (score 0):

is used when you are calling some HtmlHelper method which returns a string e.g.:

    

 is used when you are calling some HtmlHelper method which is void: